# Ruby/Rails + Resque throwing "Connection timed out" Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I have a Ruby Rails application using Resque.

The Resuqe daemon crashes after running for a while with the error. My first guess was that the daemon is not accessing the MySQL DB often enough (for several hours) so I trigger every 5 minutes a queue item that accesses the DB. But still I get:

```
rake aborted!
Connection timed out
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:204:in `rescue in io'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:202:in `io'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:210:in `read'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:84:in `block in call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:287:in `ensure_connected'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:173:in `block in process'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:248:in `logging'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:172:in `process'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:84:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis.rb:715:in `block in get'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis.rb:36:in `block in synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis.rb:36:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis.rb:714:in `get'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/redis-namespace-1.2.1/lib/redis/namespace.rb:257:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/resque-1.23.0/lib/resque/worker.rb:517:in `job'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/resque-1.23.0/lib/resque/worker.rb:450:in `unregister_worker'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/resque-1.23.0/lib/resque/worker.rb:169:in `rescue in work'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/resque-1.23.0/lib/resque/worker.rb:129:in `work'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/resque-1.23.0/lib/resque/tasks.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => resque:work
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I put some log file output in my method that gets called when any asynch task is triggered but looks as if the connection timed out happens while not executing any of my application code.

Where to go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the log here, the connection to redis is lost, not mysql.

Comment: The redis process is running. And after restarting resque all works again. What could be a reason for the connection to redis being lost?

Comment: Thanks on the hint about redis. Checked the installed version, 2.0.1, pretty old. Installed the latest from their webpage, lets see if its "stable" now.

Comment: That's probably the version indeed, how did it go ?

Comment: Its running now for roughly 4 hours. If its up and running for more than 48 hours without crashing then it was the version. I'll post an update in 45 hours.

Comment: OK, two days later and the process is still running. I conclude: must have been the "old" version in combination with the latest GEM.